# How to remove duplicate columns generated after using pd.get_dummies using their variance as cutoff

Tags: pandas, var

I have a dataframe which is being generated using pd.get_dummies as below:

```
df_target = pd.get_dummies(df_column[column], dummy_na=True,prefix=column)
```

where column is a column name and df_column is the dataframe from which each column is being pulled to do some operations.

```
rev_grp_m2_> 225    rev_grp_m2_nan  rev_grp_m2_nan
0                       0                   0
0                       0                   0
0                       0                   0
0                       0                   0
0                       0                   0
0                       0                   0
0                       0                   0
1                       0                   0
0                       0                   0
0                       0                   0
0                       0                   0
0                       0                   0
```

Now I do a check of variance for each column generated and skip those with zero variance.

```
for target_column in list(df_target.columns):
    # If variance of the dummy created is zero : append it to a list and print to log file.
    if ((np.var(df_target_attribute[[target_column]])[0] != 0)==True):
        df_final[target_column] = df_target[target_column]
```

Here due to two columns being the same , I get a Key Error for the np.var line.
There are two values of variance for the nan column:

```
erev_grp_m2_nan    0.000819
rev_grp_m2_nan    0.000000
```

Ideally I would like to take the one with non-zero variance and drop/skip the one with 0 var.

Can someone please help me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [`DataFrame.var`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.var.html) use:

```
print (df.var())
rev_grp_m2_> 225    0.083333
rev_grp_m2_nan      0.000000
rev_grp_m2_nan      0.000000
```

Last for filtering is used [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df.loc[:, df.var()!= 0]
print (out)
    rev_grp_m2_> 225
0                  0
1                  0
2                  0
3                  0
4                  0
5                  0
6                  0
7                  1
8                  0
9                  0
10                 0
11                 0
```

EDIT: You can get indices of non 0 values and then seelct by `iloc`:

```
cols = [i for i in np.arange(len(df.columns)) if np.var(df.iloc[:, i]) != 0]
print (cols)
[0]

df = df.iloc[:, cols]
print (df)
    rev_grp_m2_> 225
0                  0
1                  0
2                  0
3                  0
4                  0
5                  0
6                  0
7                  1
8                  0
9                  0
10                 0
11                 0
```

Another idea is filter out if all values are `0`:

```
cols = [i for i in np.arange(len(df.columns)) if (df.iloc[:, i] != 0).any()]
out = df.iloc[:, cols]
```

Or:

```
out = df.loc[:, (df != 0).any()]
print (out)
    rev_grp_m2_> 225
0                  0
1                  0
2                  0
3                  0
4                  0
5                  0
6                  0
7                  1
8                  0
9                  0
10                 0
11                 0
```

Comment: hello @jezrael.. Thanks a lot for the solution. But in the sample posted both the duplicate columns have zero variance and hence I can drop any using the max. However in original data the variance will be different for each of the duplicate columns. Hence I am looking for a way to use only the variance to determine the position of columns where it is not zero and drop the others.

Comment: @ShuvayanDas - OK, if omit `max` it shoud working too. Can you test it?

Comment: I had used df.var() but for some columns where number of categories is more than 50k.. this throws memory error on server. Hence I am looking for a column wise operation. Like iterating over each column, find variance, if zero, drop and proceed to the next column. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @ShuvayanDas - I add 3 solutions, please check it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jezrael.. The one with iloc is the most elegant and efficient one I think. Wish I could give starts instead of just an upvote and tick .. :)